# Direct sum of a subspace and its orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

Can someone give me an geometric and intuitive explanation for why this Theorem is right?
Direct sum of a subspace and its orthogonal complement 
Suppose U is a finite-dimensional subspace of V.
Then $V=U⊕U^⊥$

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has a geometric picture in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$.

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, you can think of $U$ as a line through the origin, and $U^\perp$ as the line through the origin perpendicular to it. For example, $U$ could be the line spanned by $(1,1)$ and $U^\perp$ the line spanned by $(-1,1)$. To get to any vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can first go along some vector in $U$, then add a vector in $U^\perp$, just like the parallelogram law for the sum of two vectors, and there is only one way to do this.

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, you can think of $U$ as a plane through the origin, and $U^\perp$ as the line through the origin that’s normal to $U$. For example, $U$ might be the $xy$-plane and $U^\perp$ the $z$-axis. To get to any point in $\mathbb{R}^3$, there is a unique way to write it as the sum of some vector in the $xy$-plane and some vector in the $z$-axis. We can first look at its “shadow” in the $xy$-plane, i.e. a point $(x,y,0)$, which corresponds to the $U$ component, and then add to this the “height” component $(0,0,z)$, which corresponds to the $U^\perp$ component.

Comment: can I add and say that if I look at $U := xy$  plane  in $ R^3$ then I can also decompose it to a subspace and its orthogonal complement ?

Comment: You can if you only consider vectors in $U$. But if you look at the entire space $R^3$, then no. For example, if you have a line $W$ in your plane $U$, the orthogonal complement "in $R^3$" of this line is a plane that isn't contained in $U$. The reason being that the orthogonal complement of $W$ is defined as all vectors *in $R^3$* that are orthogonal to $W$. However if you only ask for all vectors *in $U$* that are orthogonal to $W$, then yes you can decompose $U$ in that way.